# tkinter frame propagate not behaving?

Tags: python, tkinter

If you uncomment the options_frame_title you will see that it does not behave properly. Am I missing something? That section was just copied and pasted from the preview_frame_title and that seems to have no issues.

```
from tkinter import *


blank_app = Tk()
blank_app.geometry('750x500+250+100')
blank_app.resizable(width=False, height=False)


main_frame = Frame(blank_app, width=750, height=500, bg='gray22')
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

main_title = Label(main_frame, text='App Builder', bg='gray', fg='red', font='Times 12 bold', relief=RIDGE)
main_title.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=NSEW, columnspan=2)

preview_frame = Frame(main_frame, width=70, height=465, bg='red', highlightcolor='white', highlightthickness=2)
preview_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)

preview_frame_title = Label(preview_frame, text='Preview Window', width=70, bg='gray', fg='blue', relief=RIDGE)
preview_frame_title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

options_frame = Frame(main_frame, width=240, height=465, bg='blue', highlightcolor='white', highlightthickness=2)
options_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)

options_frame_title = Label(options_frame, text='Widget Options', width=20, bg='gray', fg='blue', anchor=CENTER, relief=RIDGE)
options_frame_title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)


blank_app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hum. Interesting. I played with it for a bit but no luck. I will work on this some more when I get home tonight. I am interested to see what is causing the change. Maybe we will get lucky and Bryan will answer the question :)

Comment: Your title says "propagate not behaving", but at no point do you actually do any such thing.  (You defined three functions that call `grid_propagate()`, but never called any of them!)

Comment: @jasonharper. Are they not supposed to go at the end of frame variable? That is where I put the commands.

Comment: Just tried adding weight and that didn't help either.

Comment: You _define_ methods in `prop` but you never _call_ them. Also, `command=props()` almost certainly isn't doing what you think it's doing. I'm not sure why you think a `Label` has a `command` attribute.

Comment: @BryanOakley I wasn't sure if they needed to be attached to the labels as well. The method props() I got from a resource online. How does propagation work? The frames seemed to be behaving correctly until that last Label.

Comment: If you are just now learning tkinter, my advice is to completely forget about turning off geometry propagation. It almost always is the wrong thing to do. Tkinter is very good at making the GUI the best size based on its content.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Why do the frames change in this way when that last label is added? It worked fine before adding that label.

Comment: As predicted Bryan was able to give a way more detailed and clear answer than I could :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "behaving properly". It seems to be behaving as it's designed to behave.

By default, tkinter frames are designed to shrink (or grow) to fit their child widgets. When you comment out `options_frame_title.grid(...)`, the frame has no visible children so it says the fixed size that you gave it.  When you uncomment that line, it causes a label to be placed in the widget which then causes the frame to shrink to fit.

To further complicate the matters for you, `grid` will by default give any extra space to rows and columns that have a non-zero weight. Since you haven't given any rows or columns any weight, they don't get any extra space.

Part of the problem is that you are trying to solve too many problems at once. When first starting out you need to be more methodical. Also, you should consider using `pack` when you're putting a single widget into another widget. It only takes one line of code to get it to fill its parent rather than three with `grid`.

---

pro-tip: it *really* helps if you separate widget creation from widget layout. Your code, even though it's only a couple dozen lines long, is really hard to read.

---

For example, the first thing you should do is start by creating your top-most frames, and get them to fill and expand/shrink properly before putting any widgets in them.

### Starting from scratch

**Step 0: don't remove the ability to resize the window**

User's don't like having control taken away from them. Remove this line:

```
blank_app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
```

Your users will thank you, and during development it's much easier to play with the window to make sure everything is filling, growing, and shrinking as necessary.

**Step 1: main_frame**

Since it appears this is designed to contain everything, it makes sense to use `pack` since it is the only widget directly in `blank_app`.

```
main_frame = Frame(blank_app, width=750, height=500, bg='gray22')
main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

With just that (plus the first couple of lines where you create the root window, along with the final call to `mainloop`), notice how the window is the right size, and the main frame fills the window. You can resize the window all you want and the main frame will continue to fill the whole window.

**Step 2: widgets inside main_frame**

As I mentioned earlier, it's best to separate widget creation and widget layout. Also, when using grid a good rule of thumb is to always give at least one row and one column a weight. It appears  you want the right frame to be about 3x as wide as the left frame. This is where you can use weights.

```
# widgets in the main frame
main_title = Label(main_frame, text='App Builder', bg='gray', fg='red', font='Times 12 bold', relief=RIDGE)
preview_frame = Frame(main_frame, width=70, height=465, bg='red', highlightcolor='white', highlightthickness=2)
options_frame = Frame(main_frame, width=240, height=465, bg='blue', highlightcolor='white', highlightthickness=2)

# laying out the main frame
main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

main_title.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew", columnspan=2)
preview_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
options_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
```

Once again, run the code and notice that as you resize the main window everything still continues to fill the window, and resize properly, and keep the proper proportions. If you don't like the proportions, just change the weights. They can be any number you want. For example, you could use 70 and 240 if you want.

**Step 3: preview frame**

The preview frame has a label, and I presume you will be putting other stuff under the label. We'll continue to use `grid`, and just give the row below the label a weight so that it gets all of the extra space. When you add more widgets, you might need to adjust accordingly.

```
# widgets in the preview frame
preview_frame_title = Label(preview_frame, text="Preview Window", bg='gray', fg='blue', relief=RIDGE)

# laying out the preview frame
preview_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
preview_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
preview_frame_title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

**Step 4: the options frame**

This is just like the preview frame: a label at the top, and all of the extra space is given to the empty row number 1.

```
# widgets in the options frame
options_frame_title = Label(options_frame, text='Widget Options', bg='gray', fg='blue', anchor=CENTER, relief=RIDGE)

# laying out the options frame
options_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
options_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
options_frame_title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="new")
```

**Final thoughs**

Notice that you don't need to worry about propagation, which is somewhat of an advanced topic. You also don't have to worry about the size of frames since we're using column weights to give relative sizes, and you don't have to give sizes to their labels.

We have removed the propagation code, removed the non-resizable behavior, and removed some hard-coded widths, giving us less code but more functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation you gave. It was very easy to understand and nice of you to go into such depth on the topic. I am new at this and only been at it for a few weeks. I did not understand how weight worked at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some digging I realized the problem was not with your `options_frame_title` but with your frames the Label was being placed in.

Of you un-comment `options_frame_title` and comment out `preview_frame_title` you will see the exact same problem. What is happening is the frame has a set size and the main window is conforming to that frame size. And when you decide to place a label into the frame then the frame will conform to the label size.

What you want to do to achieve the look you are going for is do something a little different with the `.grid_propagate(0)` than what you are currently doing.

We also need to add some weights to the correct frames so the widgets will fill properly.

Take a look at this code.

```
from tkinter import *

blank_app = Tk()

main_frame = Frame(blank_app,width=700, height=300, bg='gray22')
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

main_frame.grid_propagate(0) #the only place you need to use propagate(0) Thought there are better ways

main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) #using weights to manage frames properly helps a lot here
main_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 0)
main_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

main_title = Label(main_frame, text='App Builder', bg='gray', fg='red', font='Times 12 bold', relief=RIDGE)
main_title.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)

preview_frame = Frame(main_frame, bg='red', highlightcolor='white', highlightthickness=2)
preview_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)
preview_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)# using weights to manage frames properly helps a lot here

preview_frame_title = Label(preview_frame, text='Preview Window', bg='gray', fg='blue', relief=RIDGE)
preview_frame_title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

options_frame = Frame(main_frame, bg='blue', highlightcolor='white', highlightthickness=2)
options_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)
options_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) #using weights to manage frames properly helps a lot here

options_frame_title = Label(options_frame, text='Widget Options', bg='gray', fg='blue', anchor=CENTER, relief=RIDGE)
options_frame_title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

blank_app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bryan did explain it very well but thank you for your answer as well. The effort is much appreciated.